# How to resolve this "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" exception in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working on a `Java` Project using `Selenium`. I have attempted to implement my test codes. Below here is the snippet of it.

**AutoTest**

```
public class AutoTest {

WebDriver driver = null;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ();
    handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    //Configuration for WebDriver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath+"/drivers/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(handlSSLErr);
}

@Test
public void createTopUpRequest() {
    //browse to UAT Server
    driver.get("https://10.2.5.215:33000/viewTopUpRequest");

    //enter credentials
    LoginPage.usernameLogin(driver).sendKeys("ezltest2svc");
    LoginPage.passwordLogin(driver).sendKeys("Password123!");

    //Click on submit button
    LoginPage.loginButton(driver).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);


}

@AfterTest
public void closeBrowser() {
    //driver.close();
}

}
```

As soon as it tries navigating to this portal: "https://10.2.5.215:33000/viewTopUpRequest", I get the `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` exception. May I know how to bypass the security protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities` even provides such option.

I'm using `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public static String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
public static String chromedriverPath = userDir + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";

public static WebDriver startChromeDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

This works as well:

```
public static WebDriver startChromeDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
}
```

Tested on https://badssl.com/

Comment: Thanks bro. The 1st snippet works for me.